# Selecting columns from flat file in power shell with no column name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new to **power shell** ,and I have the below format (**pipe** delimiter) with no **column** name:

```
01|1|06/28/2017 00:00:00|06/28/2017 00:00:00
```

I want to choose the third or any column from this format,I have tried the below code :

```
$columns=(Get-Content $filepath | Out-String | select -Skip 2 -First 1).Split("|")
```

but it is not working can any one help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0) with `-Header` and `-Delimiter` specified; that way, you get a structure (`PSCustomObject[]`) with attributes that you can reference directly and meaningfully. For example,

```
$EntryList = Import-CSV -Path $FilePath -Header ID,Type,StartTime,EndTime -Delimiter '|'
```

gets you an array of PSCustomObjects, where each object has the indicated fields. You can then (for example) refer to `$EntryList[$n].ID`, `$EntryList[$n].StartTime`, and so on.

Comment: thank you for your response I have a new inquiry,if I have column out as below record_type=01,I want to filter to get only the value inside the output column

Comment: The above answer gives you all the information you need - once you have parsed out the file using the above construction, you can then manipulate the array and process it based on the field names that you assigned when you did the `Import-CSV`.